# How to hide ID from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, tabs

I've seen this type of question in Stack Overflow before and none of them help really. I've also Googled it but no dice.

I'm wondering if it's possible to hide the ID from the URL if the user clicks on the tabs itself?

This is the webpage:
**www.planet.nu/dev/new-experian/index.html**

Then when I clicked on a tab, this is what will happen:
**www.planet.nu/dev/new-experian/index.html#dataTab1**

I heard that using Javascript can actually hide that but I'm not sure how. My clients are really keen to hide such ID from appearing on the URL even though it does no harm.

This is where I got the plugin:
http://webthemez.com/demo/easy-responsive-tabs/Index.html

If there are no other solutions, then I might have to change the jQuery code for this. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've done is in 'easyResponsiveTabs.js' search for

```
var newHash = respTabsId+(parseInt($tabAria.substring(9),10)+1).toString();
```

replace the line with

```
var newHash = "";
```

and then seach for

```
newHash = '#'+newHash;
```

replace the line with

```
newHash = ''+newHash;
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you! This definitely helped me out! :D

Answer (score 0):

try jquery `$("body").scrollTop()` function. it will not show the id in the url bar and try *not to use many plugins*.

 
`$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#dividhere').position().top}, 'fast');`

Answer (score 0):

You could use:
   window.history.pushState('object or string', 'Title', '/index.html');

Or:
    window.history.replaceState('object or string', 'Title', '/index.html');

I often use it - you can find a more detailed explanation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Answer (score 0):

What you are calling an "id" is a "hash", the hash is used to scroll to an anchor (by default) or can be used by JavaScript to signal things like tab switches, or internal page switches, or really anything you want. You don't always want to remove them (because it might break some JS functionality) but if you do want to you can use:

```
location.hash = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use plugins you don't understand. This was made [on purpose](https://github.com/samsono/Easy-Responsive-Tabs-to-Accordion/blob/master/js/easyResponsiveTabs.js#L192). Of course you can modify this plugin - set `historyApi` to `false` in line 24, but I advise to write some code from scratch and learn jQuery. Simple tabs are basics. Level 0... It's not hard.